# GPS Datalogger with USB Interface and GPX Output

Tags: gps, gpx

I'm looking for a reliable, robust and reasonably priced GPS datalogger, to measure time, distance on tracks. The logger should be reasonably priced but ready for outdoor activities. Mud, dirt, a little water shouldn't harm the device. Another point is, it has to be plugged into a PC/Mac and handled as a normal USB drive to download the GPX files. GPX File is a must have as well.

To summarize the needs:

- GPX
- USB drive / no proprietary software
- reliable

If anyone is a GPS crack, I'm happily to get an answer!

Thanks Martin

Comment: would add fast gps fix and accuracy to the list - here is a cheap one - http://www.amazon.com/i-Blue-Bluetooth-Receiver-Waypoints-iBlue747A/dp/B001LK19G2/ref=sr_1_8?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1349275117&sr=1-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took mapperz advice and ordered a iBlue 747pro.

Comment: Hi just wondering if this device lasted and worked as expected, do you still use it?

Comment: I've been using this recently its been pretty good, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger&hl=en_GB

Answer (score 3):

After spending a LOT of time looking around and reading reviews, I recently purchased a Garmin eTrex 20 for hiking purposes:

[http://www.amazon.com/Garmin-eTrex-Worldwide-Handheld-Navigator/dp/B00542NVDW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00542NVDW)

Price was definitely a factor, along with functionality, durability and ease of use.  I particularly like the way Basecamp (Garmin software) allows you to download hiking trails from OSM straight onto the GPS.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the [i-gotU GT-600](http://global.mobileaction.com/product/product_i-gotU_GT-600.jsp). It's a logger--no screen, etc. Pretty simple device. Has a motion sensor so it shuts off when not moving to save battery life. It doesn't plug directly in via USB, but has a cable. I'm not 100% sure how the PC/Mac will recognize it though; it may need special software to access the .gpx.